# Select das cidades e estados no site

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados, select

Estou montando um *site*, e na página inicial eu criei um `select` para os estados e as cidades, o problema é que a página inicial do *site* está travando muito.

Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer esse `select` sem travar o *site*? Ou talvez fazer de outra maneira?

O link do site é http://www.simplemed.com.br

```
<?php 

ItemForm::region_select(osc_get_regions(osc_user_region()), osc_user()); ?> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="cell selector">
        <!--------------City-------------------->
        <?php ItemForm::city_select(osc_get_cities(osc_user_region()), osc_user()); ?>
        <!--------------City End-------------------->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="cell reset-padding">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_search">
            <?php _e( "Search", 'osclasswizards');?> </button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="message-seach"></div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#regionId").on("change", function() {
            var pk_c_code = $(this).val(); <? php
            if ($path == "admin") { ?>
                var url = '<?php echo osc_admin_base_url(true)."?page=ajax&action=cities&regionId="; ?>'
                pk_c_code; <? php
            } else { ?>
                var url = '<?php echo osc_base_url(true)."?page=ajax&action=cities&regionId="; ?>'
                pk_c_code; <? php
            }; ?>
            var result = '';
            if (pk_c_code != '') {
                $("#cityId").attr('disabled', false);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var length = data.length;
                        if (length > 0) {
                            result = '<option selected value=""><?php _e("Select a city..."); ?></option>';
                            for (key in data) {
                                result = '<option value="'
                                data[key].pk_i_id '">'
                                data[key].s_name '</option>';
                            }
                            $("#city").before('<select name="cityId" id="cityId" ></select>');
                            $("#city").remove();
                        } else {
                            result = '<option value=""><?php _e('
                            No results ') ?></option>';
                            $("#cityId").before('<input type="text" name="city" id="city" />');
                            $("#cityId").remove();
                        }
                        $("#cityId").html(result);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#cityId").attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
        if ($("#regionId").attr('value') == "") {
            $("#cityId").attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Poste seu código, como você está fazendo, se você está buscando tudo de uma vez ou conforme a seleção...

Comment: bem vindo ao stackoverflow português, por favor leia o [ask], seria interessante colocar o código existente ou o link para sua página

Comment: @Victor, Já rodou o [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) no seu site?

Comment: @ctgPi, não conheço o PageSpeed Insights

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML renderizado?

Comment: Esses dias atrás o @Sergio me ajudou a implementar esse script: http://jsfiddle.net/w938st7q/2/ No fiddle está só com dois estados, mas você pode baixar [aqui](https://code.google.com/p/cidades-estados-js/).

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99107/listar-estados-cidades-e-bairros-em-formul%C3%A1rio-de-cadastro/99133#99133

Answer (score 0):

O problema imediato não parece ser nem a consulta nem o jQuery: a sua página principal tem **mais de um megabyte**! A primeira ordem de negócios é você empurrar a consulta que puxa a lista de cidades pra uma outra página e carregar via AJAX (a *segunda* ordem de negócios é, na página que puxa a lista de cidades, filtrar pelo estado que o usuário escolheu).

Eu não vi o código que você escreveu, mas pelo visto você está puxando o dado via PHP (que gera o tijolo a que eu me referi acima) e depois faz o AJAX (pra puxar o dado que já veio na primeira execução); dá um Ctrl+S e olha o tamanho do arquivo resultante pra você ver que a lista de cidades está vindo no carregamento original da página.

Comment: A pagina inicial estava com mais de 2mb, eu fiz o seguinte, deletei as cidades do banco e mandei carregar a pagina novamente, agora está abrindo bem mais rápido. Porém quando eu clico em "Selecionar uma cidade" ele já abre as cidades que estão cadastradas no banco, sem que eu selecione o estado.

Comment: É exatamente esse o problema, você não pode popular a lista de cidades no carregamento inicial da página.

Comment: Como eu faço esse carregamento em outra página?